# Context.Request.Query["id"] return null in View

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to get "id" parameter in View, but `Context.Request.Query["id"]` return null value.

Query like this:**`localhost:1000/MyController/Getuser/65190907-1145-7049-9baa-d68d44b1ad06`**

```
// Controller
public ActionResult Getuser(Guid id)
{
    //HttpContext.Request.Query["id"] also return null
    return View();
}

//in startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Does the id parameter of Getuser method not return the id?

Comment: Yes, id parameter was bind OK in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can get it by `ViewContext.ModelState["id"].AttemptedValue`

Answer (score 1):

`Request.Query` contains query string of the request, i.e. URL part that goes after question mark: `...?param1=value1&param2=value2`. URL `localhost:1000/MyController/Getuser/65190907-1145-7049-9baa-d68d44b1ad06` does not contain query string. GUID `65190907-1145-7049-9baa-d68d44b1ad06` is just a part of URL path.

If for some reason you want to access id parameter from raw request, not via Model Binding, you have two options:

1. Pass `id` in query string and access it via `HttpContext.Request.Query["id"]`:

   In this case request URL will be `http://localhost:1000/MyController/Getuser?id=65190907-1145-7049-9baa-d68d44b1ad06`. No changes in routes are required.
2. The second option is to extract `id` from `Request.Path`:

   ```
   public IActionResult Getuser(Guid id)
   {
       var path = HttpContext.Request.Path;
       var id2 = Guid.Parse(path.Value.Split('/').Last());

       return View();
   }
   ```